# Are seventh and extended chords used to create dream-like and fantasy music?

Tags: theory, composition, harmony

There's an arpeggio that I've heard in different songs and it usually signifies some kind of transition into a "dream world". Here's an example of it, which happens for the first few seconds of [Great Fairy's Fountain](https://youtu.be/ZePGCUdpWnM?t=4). The arpeggio that's going on involves a **C9 chord**. Similarly in dance of the [Sugar Plum Fairies](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YRvvzCZvtmU&t=70) there's a predominant **B7 chord** in their arpeggios, here's an [analysis](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/74382/harmonic-analysis-of-arpeggios-in-dance-of-the-sugar-plum-fairy). Note that both songs have the word fairy in them.

I was wondering if it's safe to say that this sound is due to them using seventh and extended chords. And if I wanted to achieve this type of sound does it usually involve arpeggiating some type of seventh/extended chord, basically something more than just a triad?

Answer (score 1):

The question might be more subjective than objective - and so will be the answer:

It is more the arpeggio itself than the V79(13) chord that evokes this effect. It might be as well a whole tone scale or pentatonic scale for this.

In the music of Debussy you'll find many examples for this (flutes or harps): <

e.g. l'après midi d'un faune

[image]